# Is it possible to start a brodacast receiver from android WorkManager class in Java/Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-workmanager

I am stuck with one question for more than one month now. I want to start a broadcast receiver from an Android  WorkManager class. I want to receive/filter all incoming text messages and then post to a server. However, my current solution cannot work for many hours before the android system kills the app and the receiver sync stops, or by the time I extract the text message from the PDU object (coming from telephone Intent) is onReceive method has already returned. 
Therefore to solve this I wish to keep broadcast onReceive method running inside a WorkManager to ensure the process does not terminate so fast.  I have tried reading but I am not getting the kind of solution that works well with me, or maybe there is something not clear to me about the Broadcast Receiver or how android background processes work.
This is my current implementation. 
Below is the onReceive() method as implemented on the MessageReceiver that extends BroadcastReceiver

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context= context;
        if (Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
           final Bundle data = intent.getExtras();

            if (data !=null ) {
                try {
                    final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) data.get("pdus");
                    if (pdusObj != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                            SmsMessage currentMessage =
                                    SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                            Log.d(TAG, "run: currentMessage: " + currentMessage);

                            Log.d(TAG, "passReceivedMsg: handleMessage: message " + currentMessage);

                            int msgNo = counter++;
                            msgID = "SMS_ID_0" + msgNo;
                            sender = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                            text_message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                            long timestampMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            timestamp = formatter.format(timestampMilliseconds);

                            Data.Builder dataBuilder = new Data.Builder();
                            dataBuilder.putString("sender",sender);
                            dataBuilder.putString("message",text_message);
                            dataBuilder.putString("timestamp",timestamp);
                            dataBuilder.putString("sms_id",msgID);
//                            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive:  key:" +key+ " and keyValue "+data.get(key));

                            WorkManager mWorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance();
                            OneTimeWorkRequest mRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest
                                    .Builder(MessageSyncWorker.class)
                                    .setInputData(dataBuilder.build())
                                    .build();
                            mWorkManager.enqueue(mRequest);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: Exception occured "+e.getMessage());
                }
            }


       }

    }
```

Below is my  MessageSyncWorker class that extends the Worker- doWork ()method

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {

Data inputData1 = getInputData();

sender = inputData1.getString("sender");
text_message = inputData1.getString("message");
timestamp = inputData1.getString("timestamp");
msgID = inputData1.getString("sms_id");
Log.d(TAG, "doWork: Mesage "+text_message);

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
BASE_API_URL = sharedPreferences.getString("settings_server_url", "");

Log.d(TAG, "doWork: BASE URL "+BASE_API_URL);

try {
    //here I upload the data to the server
    uploadMessageData();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.d(TAG, "doWork: uploadMessage method Exception "+e.getMessage());
}


return Result.success();
}
```

Comment: Why are you thinking that getting `onReceive()` to run longer, or again, will help? Manifest-registered Receiver instances are very temporary things, and they're supposed to be. When a message arrives, a new instance of your Receiver is created, and the broadcast is passed into its `onReceive()`, which should complete as quickly as possible. When that's done, the Receiver instance is done, too, and will go away very shortly. Queueing work with `WorkManager` is near-instantaneous, so there's no reason for your Receiver or its `onReceive()` method to be active any longer than that.

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact behavior you're observing, but I would point out that you don't seem to be handling the incoming messages quite correctly, assuming that `MessageSyncWorker` is meant to run only once for each message. Your Receiver will only ever be passed one message at a time, though it may be in multiple parts. Each element in the `pdusObj` array is _not_ a separate message, but one part of a multipart message. You need to concatenate the message bodies to get the complete, single message, before queueing the `WorkManager` job. Perhaps the undesired behavior is related to that.

Comment: the onReceive () is already on its own class that extends broadcast receiver. However, the method returns even before calling the work manager class since I am doing the operations to get the message from PDU which seems to delay. This is where my challenge is.  With the current implementation, I observed that at some point the incoming message does not sync with the server. After doing some research I noticed the onReceive() is returning so quicky before I get the message elements from the PDU object. This is where I am stuck.

Comment: That's why I mention what I do in the second comment: I think you might be misinterpreting the observed behavior. You should expect `onReceive()` to be done well before your `MessageSyncWorker` runs. The `enqueue()` call is just queueing a job to happen at some later time. Your code doesn't pause and wait for it to happen. And, as I allude to above, long messages are going to be multipart. You're currently queueing a job for each individual part, so if you're debugging in `MessageSyncWorker`, it might look like it didn't complete, because it's only part of the message.

Comment: I now get it.  I can now see what you meant on the second comment. lemme try it out.

Comment: Well, to fix the multipart thing, you just need to rearrange your code to only concatenate the parts' message bodies in the `for` loop, and then set up and `enqueue()` the job after the loop; something like https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HEoGngzSqAOhc_aU8lJvTk2aLdkhDca3/view?usp=sharing. (I didn't test that; just moved it around to give you the idea.) I'm not sure, though, that it fully explains the behavior you're seeing, but it's the first thing I would do.

Comment: Your argument makes more sense now. I initiated a very long message with my current implementation. I noticed the message-body came in two parts and one part got lost did sync well with the server but after using the StringBuilder to concatenate, as you recommended I have received the text as one part.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have cracked it after a detailed discussion as can be seen in the comments area (for this question). I now have working code, and I trust by sharing I can help someone else stuck with similar. Below is how I did it.
here is the onReceive() method;

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION
                .equals(intent.getAction())){
            this.context = context;
            SmsMessage smsMessage = null;
            StringBuilder fullMessage = new StringBuilder();
            for (SmsMessage new_smsMessage : Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)){
                smsMessage = new_smsMessage;
                fullMessage.append(smsMessage.getDisplayMessageBody());
            }
            if (smsMessage ==null){
                return;
            }

            String sender = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
            long timestampMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
            String timestamp = formatter.format(timestampMilliseconds);

            Log.d("NeTxt Receiver ", "onReceive: fullMessage: "+fullMessage);

            Data.Builder dataBuilder = new Data.Builder();
            dataBuilder.putString("fullMessage",fullMessage.toString());
            dataBuilder.putString("sender", sender);

            dataBuilder.putString("timestamp",timestamp);


            //defining constraints
            Constraints task_constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                    .build();

            //scheduling the work
            WorkManager mWorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance();
            OneTimeWorkRequest mRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest
                    .Builder(NewTxtWorker.class)
                    .setInputData(dataBuilder.build())
                    .setConstraints(task_constraints)
                    .build();
            mWorkManager.enqueue(mRequest);

            mWorkManager.getWorkInfoById(mRequest.getId());

        }

    }
```

below is my doWork() method;

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {

    Data inputData = getInputData();
    String sender = inputData.getString("sender");
    String text_message = inputData.getString("fullMessage");
    String timestamp = inputData.getString("timestamp");

    Log.d("Txt WorkManager", "doWork: fullmessage: "+text_message);


    assert sender != null;
    assert text_message != null;
    if (!timestamp.isEmpty()||
            !sender.isEmpty()||
            !text_message.isEmpty()){

        FirebaseFirestore fireDb = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        Map<String, Object> message = new HashMap<>();
        message.put("text_message", text_message);
        message.put("sender", sender);
        message.put("timestamp", timestamp);
        //sync the received message with the firebase firestore db
        fireDb.collection("text_messages")
                .add(message)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                        Log.d("Txt WorkManager", "onSuccess: doc Id"
                                +documentReference.getId());
                    }
                })
               .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                       Log.d("Txt WorkManager", "onFailure: "+e.getMessage());
                   }
               }) ;

    }

    return Result.failure();
}
```